# Undefined control sequence \uline in exporting org-mode with underline markup to PDF using xelatex

Tags: org-mode, org-export, latex, pdf

For the following sample,

```
#+LATEX_CMD: xelatex
#+LATEX_HEADER: \usepackage{xltxtra}
#+OPTIONS: ^:nil

This is a _test_
```

The export to PDF uses xelatex would produce the following error:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
l.28 This is a \uline
                     {test}
? 
! Emergency stop.
l.28 This is a \uline
                     {test}
No pages of output.
```

If I use pdflatex then there is no such error. (I have to use xelatex for exporting text with Chinese.)

What would be the solution with xelatex?

Comment: Does `#+LATEX_HEADER: \usepackage{ulem}\usepackage{fixltx2e}` help? The `fixltx2e` hint with respect to `xelatex` is from https://golatex.de/xelatex-freeze-mit-paketen-mhchem-ulem-fontspec-t11962.html.

Comment: Yes, and actually, adding #+LATEX_HEADER: \usepackage{ulem}
alone would make it work as expected. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The LaTeX command `\uline` is defined in the LaTeX package `ulem`.
You can load that package during PDF export with the following line in your org-file.

```
#+LATEX_HEADER: \usepackage{ulem}
```

Fine if that already helps.
Nevertheless a problem of `ulem` with `XeLaTeX` is reported at [golatex.de](https://golatex.de/xelatex-freeze-mit-paketen-mhchem-ulem-fontspec-t11962.html).
Following that thread the workaround would be:

```
#+LATEX_HEADER: \usepackage{ulem}\usepackage{fixltx2e}
```

Note that in `org-version` 9.1.6 `ulem` is already present in `org-latex-default-packages-alist` as entry `("normalem" "ulem" t)`.

If you have already that or a newer version of org-mode then it might be that  you have modified `org-latex-default-packages-alist` and that list is not upgraded for you.

Otherwise you could just upgrade to the newest stable version of org-mode from [melpa](https://github.com/melpa/melpa). If you do not like to upgrade for any reason maybe you can add the `ulem` entry to `org-latex-default-packages-alist`.

Comment: Thanks, indeed, I have customized `org-latex-default-packages-alist` with probably partial and outdated content without `("normalem" "ulem" t)`